# How to search text in a long paragraph and auto scroll to found text in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, search, scroll

Friends, I have a long paragraph displaying in Text() widget in body part of mobile screen. I have added a search text box to search in app bar in Flutter.

My query is that how can we search a text in that long paragraph and if it is found then scroll automatically and show that text in long paragraph?

If anyone have any previous experience or any suggestion. Please share with me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you get the logic ???

Comment: @VirajD, Not yet dear, still searching... do you have any clue to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Any solution there?

Comment: @urvashi still searching solution, kindly share you find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first declared variable

`final ItemScrollController _scrollController = ItmScrollController();`

ItemScrollController is a class in Flutter that provides control over scrolling behavior in a scrollable widget. It can be used to programmatically scroll to specific items within a scrollable list or grid. By assigning an instance of ItemScrollController to a scrollable widget, you can access methods and properties to manipulate and retrieve information about the scrolling state.

```
void _animateToIndex(String mySearch) {
    final vm =
        _ViewModel.fromStore(StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context), widget.search);
    final messages = vm.messages;
    for (int i = oldSrarch == mySearch ? firstIndex + 1 : 0;
        i < messages.length;
        i++) {
      if (messages[i].content.contains(mySearch)) {
        firstIndex = i;
        oldSrarch = mySearch;
        break;
      }
    }
    // if (firstIndex != -1) {
    _scrollController.scrollTo(
      index: firstIndex,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
    );
    // }
  }
```

This is function look for the text and scrolls there

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(ChatList oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    // if (widget.data != oldWidget.data) {
    _animateToIndex(widget.search);
    // }
  }
```

The function _animateToIndex makes any changes in the widget
If you want, you can do it when you press a button or when you press enter on the keyboard
by listening to the keyboard